# Why has Mr. Community pushed the following question to the top of the active line?

Tags: support

For some reason the following [question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/373119/use-of-have-had-had-had-has-had) has been brought to the attention of the community. The question is clearly off-topic despite the upvotes and the correct answers.

I know that from time to time Mr. Community  bring to the attention of users questions with no answers or with no upvotes, but what’s the purpose for this question?

Comment: Look at the [revision history](https://english.stackexchange.com/posts/373119/revisions). Note that 'Community' just edited it. That's why it was bumped. But then how does 'Community' edit? I think by having an edit approved?

Answer (score 4):

In this particular case, an unregistered user (listed as 'Community') made an edit which was approved, hence bumping the question to the top.

But Community's usual activity (in this context) is simply to churn the list by bumping questions that have no upvoted answers. There is no "purpose" to this mechanical process; if the question is still open, it is eligible to be bumped to the top of the list.  So if you think a question should be closed, there actually is a purpose in closevoting/flagging it, even if it is (apparently) safely off the front page.